# JSX get width of a div element

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the following in JSX and I'm trying to get the width of an element:

```
edit() {

  const width = document.getElementsByClassName('my-container').offsetWidth;

  console.log(width);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>Stuff...</div>
      <div className="my-container">
        ...
      </div>
      <div>More stuff...</div>
    </Fragment>
  )

}
```

For some reason `width` returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `const width = document.getElementsByClassName('.my-container').offsetWidth` - try that

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return an array of elements, except for the fact that it might not have actually rendered yet, you have to access the elements of the dom selection call (personally, I might actually go for the `ref = div => this.myContainer = div` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the element is not yet rendered and added to the DOM. To do that you need to use »[refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)« like so:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div ref={node => node && console.log(node.offsetWidth)}
  );
}
```

**Thanks to the comment of @Icepickle**: Keep in mind that the `node` may be null, in case the component is removed. This can be an opportunity to make some »clean up«.

You need pass in a function which is triggered when after the node was created and added to the dom.

In React dom-elements are virtual in first place, so the »real« Dom Node is kind of hidden away. That is what one of the backbones, to make react as performant as it is, since all the algorithms only process »simple JS Objects«, no full fleshed DOM nodes.

To fully understand what is going on it is helpful to remember that a line like:

```
const node = <div>;
```

will be transformed into something like this by the react babel plugin:

```
const node = React.createElement('div');
```

So finally

```
render () {

  return <div />
}
```

will result in

```
render () {

  return React.createElement('div')
}
```

And even if you would:

```
render () {
  const node = <div />;
  // that is a virtual react node, so you cannot query the
  // width here
  return node;
}
```

If you take the `document.querySelector` road you run the risk to either get no node at all (not created yet), or end up with the node before it is updated by react, so the width you measure might not/wont be the one you are after. Using `refs` ensures that the node can be accessed after all the modifications are applied.

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

Comment: don't forget that `node` will be `null` on the unmount change, no?

Comment: Good Point! can add that…

Answer (score 1):

There's no way this can work because the DOM you are referencing probably (`my-container`) does not exist yet at the moment you are calling `edit`.

If `edit` is called in the initial `render` then you can move that `getElementByClassName` call in `componentDidMount`.

If `edit` is called as response to user interaction (so *after* `componentDidMount`) then you can move the `getElementByClassName` call in `componentDidUpdate`.

Also I'd recommend using a `ref` here instead (like @philipp described in his answer).